# iPhone proximity sensor in landscape not available?

Tags: iphone, landscape, sensors, proximity

Is the proximity sensor available in landscape mode?

It only seems to work for me when I'm in portrait...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is deliberate or a bug but apparently proximity sensor only works when the statusBar is in portraitOrientation so:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
```

...does the trick.

Comment: but where i put this line. in viewDidLoad or viewWillappear.